# Accelerometer Android "Unfortunately, has stopped"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I'm now learning accelerometer for android, I found some code and try to make an accelerometer, but my apps suddenly stopped with message "Unfortunately, *** has stopped"
I have checked other Qs about this, but I found nothing helped.
I'm really newbie in android coding...

Here's my Java Code :

```
package paket.accelerometer_axis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class accelerometer_axis extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
private SensorManager sensorManager;
TextView xCoor; 
TextView yCoor; 
TextView zCoor; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer_axis);

xCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xcoor); 
yCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ycoor); 
zCoor=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.zcoor); 

sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.registerListener(this,
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);}

public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor,int accuracy){
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){

if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

float x=event.values[0];
float y=event.values[1];
float z=event.values[2];

xCoor.setText("X: "+x);
yCoor.setText("Y: "+y);
zCoor.setText("Z: "+z);
}}}
```

Here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:padding="4dip">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/icon"
android:contentDescription="@string/description_logo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
/>

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"

android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="@string/text0"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"

android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:text="@string/text1"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/xcoor"
android:text="@string/text2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/ycoor"
android:text="@string/text3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/zcoor"
android:text="@string/text4"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my Manifest :

> ```
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />  
>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
> <application          android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".Accelerometer_axis"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_accelerometer_axis" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: Can you provide the logcat ?

Comment: Ohh... I already solved this code just now..  :)

Thanks a lot anyway for ur comment...

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept it (Just to help others that may face your same problem)

Comment: http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/ accelerometer android example